# Is there a way to import an extension method for a number type into IronPython code?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ironpython

I want to import the number extensions from the compiled C# assembly to the IronPython code. Various extension methods seem to be imported ok, but not the ones for the number types.

I have defined int, double and float extensions, but code like `50.Seconds()` gives an unexpected token (Seconds) error. Is there any workaround to add a number type extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(1).__index__()
```

may work.It is a part of the language when you put braces.I can't check that for IronPython right now :)

Answer (score 2):

Calling methods on literals isn't part of the Python language:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> 1.conjugate()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1.conjugate()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> x.conjugate()
1
>>>
```

The extension methods should work on variables, just not literals.

Comment: Thanks, I have guessed so, but thought that there is a workaround for literals too.